# Testing in ktor with multiple modules

Tags: ktor, kotest

I'm toying around with a small ktor webapp where I want to split functionality in multiple modules.
I have a root module where I install the features I want to use throughout the whole application

```
fun Application.rootModule(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
        }
    }
....
```

and a domain module where I'm implementing domain functionality

```
fun Application.bookModule() {

    routing {
        get("/books/{id}") {
          ....
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement a test for this functionality

```
class BookControllerTests: StringSpec({

    "get should return correct book"{
        withTestApplication({bookModule()}) {
            val testCall: TestApplicationCall = handleRequest(method = HttpMethod.Get, uri = "/books/42") {
            }
            testCall.response.status() shouldBe HttpStatusCode.OK
        }
    }

})
```

If I run it like this, I get the error message `Response pipeline couldn't transform 'class org.codeshards.buecherkiste.book.domain.Book' to the OutgoingContent` - so content negotiation is not working. Which makes sense since this is installed in the root module which is not called here. I solved this problem by wrapping the root module and the domain module in a test module that is implemented along my test case:

```
fun Application.bookModuleTest() {
    rootModule()
    bookModule()
}
```

and this now seems to work.

Since I'm a noob when ktor and kotest are concerned I'd like to ask for feedback on this solution. Is this a proper way to do what I want or am I setting myself up for trouble down the line? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a proper way to test an application because modules don't depend on each other and are bound via configuration. Also, instead of adding one more extension method for `Application`, you can introduce the following helper function just for testing:

```
fun <T> testApp(test: TestApplicationEngine.() -> T): T {
    return withTestApplication(
        {
            rootModule()
            bookModule()
        }, 
        test
    )
}
```